# Aws Route53 to Aws RDS CNAME TTLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-rds, amazon-route53, cname

I'm setting an AWS Route53 CNAME alias to an AWS RDS Cluster endpoint. The purpose of this is to create a consistent DNS entry that will always redirect to the current cluster endpoint. However, I'm not sure what to set the CNAME TTL too.

ex.

- R53 DNS (CNAME) => RDS Cluster DNS
- db.myapp.com => cluster-abc.could-change.aws.com

AWS sets the TTL on their Cluster endpoint to 5 sec so that it can redirect to the active writer during a fail-over. When I first created the CNAME I mimic'ed that 5 sec, but I'm afraid that means it'll be forced to do two DNS lookups every 5 sec. One to get the latest CNAME value, and another to that endpoint to get the current IP.

Is this assumption correct? If so would you suggest I set the custom DNS CNAME TTL to something like 60 sec? That way systems using that custom DNS only re-query the CNAME value every 60 sec, but query the Cluster endpoint every 5 sec as expected?

Also, I know the suggestion is to set a higher TTL on DNS, but if it's higher than a few minutes it'll be possible that a system could try to use a cluster that's already been replaced.

Comment: You seem to be correctly aware of how everything works.

Comment: Great, ty @DusanBajic
It seemed pretty straight forward, but I'm not an expert in DNS

Answer (score 1):

Set the CNAME for the Route53 DNS Record to 5 seconds.

Some tutorials also advise setting it to 30 seconds, but don't exceed that value for a cluster endpoint.

Also, if you are using Java, make sure your JVM settings respect the DNS TTL. Might as well research this for your JVM version.

Concerning your question if this will be fetched twice, the answer is no, it won't. It will query the Route53 record, if 5 seconds passed, it will have also passed on the Cluster endpoint CNAME, so then it goes directly to the A RECORD for the DB Instance.